# jetpack compose swipe back for navigation does not remember PrimaryTabRow selectedIndex

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm finding that when I navigate to a page and then swipe back the `selectedTabIndex` is not remembered and always end back up at 0. Is there a way to remember the index value when changing views?  Thanks!

```
var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val tabs = listOf("Never Give", "You Up")


       PrimaryTabRow(
                selectedTabIndex = tabIndex
            ) {
                tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                    Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                        selected = tabIndex == index,
                        onClick = { tabIndex = index }
                    )
                }
            }
            when (tabIndex) {
                0 -> SomeView()
                1 -> AnotherView()
            }
```

Comment: If you want the variable saved, is there a reason you aren't using `rememberSaveable`?

Comment: I'm not following, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Using `rememberSaveable` instead of `remember` on values you want saved

Comment: I thought I replied to this, but I guess I did not. This worked out perfectly for me. Thank you!